# Installing and using ActivePresenter with Wine

Tags: wine, winetricks

I can't get Active Presenter working on wine. After installation, program shows message that "Windows 7 or newer is needed in order to use this app". The problem is, wine is set to Windows 7 x64. I've also tried changing to win 10, even installing Active Presenter using PlayOnLinux, but it shows the same error. I've installed all vcredists (except 2005) and some .NET packages using winetricks. Also, I think it's good to mention that this problem occurs on clean Windows 7, but is simply being fixed when you run Windows Update and let it download ~1GB of updates (I've checked that on vbox)
Does anybody have any idea what I should do in order to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

ActivePresenter 7.x requires Platform Update to run properly because it uses Direct2D for recording and rendering, that's why it runs fine after you run Windows Updates.

ActivePresenter 6 doesn't require that and run fine without Platform Update. It's still available at https://atomisystems.com/download/